# FPGA flash memory programming

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

I'm trying to run [this example](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/Linux_with_MMU_on_VEEK/t-Pad#Unfortunately.2C_if_you_don.27t_have_VEEK.2Ft-PAD_kit.2C_but_you_have_DE2-115...) because I have a DE2-115.

I get this debug output then I don't know what to do

```
nios2-flash-programmer --debug --epcs --base=0x0a001800 tPad_Selector.flash
Using cable "USB-Blaster [2-2]", device 1, instance 0x00
Resetting and pausing target processor: 
OK
Processor data bus width is 32 bits
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001800 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 0001703A 04C00074 9801483A 9CFFF804 983FFD1E 0000203A
  Not here: reserved fields are non-zero
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001900 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 92400237 4A40100C 483FFD26 90000135 92400237 4A40200C
  Not here: reserved fields are non-zero
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001A00 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 108001C4 1004D0FA 002EE03A 003F9C06 002EE03A 003F9506
  Not here: reserved fields are non-zero
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001B00 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
  Not here: SPI_SLAVE_SEL has 0 valid bits (should be between 1 and 16)
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001C00 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 00000000 00000000 00000260 00000000 00000000 00000001
  Valid registers found
EPCS signature is 0x16
EPCS identifier is 0x010216
No EPCS layout data - looking for section [EPCS-010216]
Unable to use EPCS device
Leaving target processor paused
```

What is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully the wiki page that you mentioned, you can find the following tip:

> When you execute the 'nios2-flash-programmer' command, you may get an error like:
>
> *No EPCS layout data - looking for section [EPCS-010216]*
>
> In such case, please refer the Altera forum page for the 'nios2-flash-programmer' or the section
>   "A. Non-Standard Flash Memories" of "Nios II Flash Programmer User Guide" at pp.23.

Nios II Flash Programmer User Guide Appendix A: Non-Standard Flash Memories can be found [here](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_nios2_flash_programmer.pdf), pp. 27.